# rosmake can't find package, but it's in ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

Tags: ros, rosws, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to build http://wiki.ros.org/april_tags_node.
I did these commands to add the package to ros workspace.

```
$ cd ~/rosbuild_ws
$ rosws set apriltag --svn https://utexas-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
$ rosws update apriltag
$ source setup.bash
```

but "$ rosmake apriltag" gives me this error.

```
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['apriltag']                                
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/calanchue/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20160428-114104
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['apriltag'] to:
[]                                   
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['apriltag']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.
```

Weird thing is that $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH surely contains apriltag package.

```
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/home/calanchue/rosbuild_ws/apriltag:/home/calanchue/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233110/rosmake-can%27t-find-package,-but-it%27s-in-ros_package_path/) by [jinhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25685/jinhwan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-04-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the package name is `april_tags_node`. Have you tried that instead?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jinhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25685/jinhwan/) on 2016-04-28**:
@ahendrix That was exact my mistake. The problem is solved. thank!